# Graphic highlighting of the cluster decays on a nuclide map

Tags: cluster-computing, physics, nuclide-editor

[image]

I would like to know how the *cluster decays* were graphically highlighted at a  *table of nuclides*.  
For example at Uranium-230 or 232 to 236.

(I plan to implement that with LaTeX/TikZ. I only know older versions, where these special decays have not been highlighted.)

Could anyone help me or have access to a table of nuclides; and could maybe post me a foto etc.?

The normal graphical annotation (for alpha, beta, gamma,... decay) is known: 
[image]